# Multithreading - returning value from thread from threadpool C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have following problem on my university project. I have to create GUI in C# and two DDLs solving the same problem. My project is about solving integral using trapezoidal rule. I have some conditions to fulfil for this project:

- I have to implement multithreading
- Maximum number of threads working at the same time should be specified by user
- Thread after completing its task should take another one from the queue
- One of two DDLs is written in Assembler

I thought that treadpool from System.threading would fit this problem perfectly. And it would but there is one problem. I have thought about the solution working like this:

- in my DDls i would have a function that returns an area of singular trapeze
- in C# i would assign threads to count areas of trapezes and summing values of them

And there is problem because it seems that it is not possible to return value using QueueUserWorkItem method from threadpool - it simply invokes functions but the value cannot be assigned after completing task. I could pass a variable as an argument and then store the value at array or sth like this but as far as i know i wont be able to handle this way of solving problem when i will use DDL in assembler. How should i come at this problem? I should finish this without returning any values? (how?) or maybe there is a way to return this value from thread at all?

Comment: Your university project is to write a DLL in assembler?  Wow.  That's hairy stuff, and something I've not done since developing for Windows 95 !

Comment: Use the `Task<double>` class, it has a Result property.

Comment: @Neil yeah i have to but this ddl is a bit small one because it has to contain only one function that  will be imported in C#

Comment: @HansPassant but is it possible to specify amount of threads that will be working at the same time? And is it possible to work like threadpool? (thread after finising its task will take another one from the queue?) because i have to avoid following situation - thread is being created and after finishing its task it disappears and another one is created for next task

Comment: Re, "I have to implement multithreading." Nit pick, but that's the wrong word. You have to _use_ multithreading. If you were implementing it, that would mean you were designing a system that allows other people to write multi-threaded code.

Comment: I don't use C#, but I bet you could use [`future` objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/future-class?view=msvc-170). The basic idea is, the caller creates a `future`, and passes it in to the called function along with whatever other arguments. The called function runs in some other thread, and eventually it _completes_ the future by assigning a value to it. Meanwhile, the caller can inquire whether the future has been completed, can _wait_ for the the future to be completed, and when it _is_ completed, the caller can `get()` the value...

Comment: ...Thread pools I have worked with in other languages provide a simplified API in which the thread pool creates and completes the `future` object for you, and your own code only has to `get()` the value. But like I said, I don't know how that works in C#.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes you are right, i need to use it not implement it

Comment: i will look these future objects up

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is probably the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method. This method takes as argument a `Func<TResult>`, schedules this function for execution on the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), and returns a [`Task<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1). After returning the task, the `Func<TResult>` is normally invoked immediately on a background thread, unless the `ThreadPool` is saturated (all its threads are currently busy). When the invocation completes, the result of the function is stored in the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property of the task.

You can query at any time the [`IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted) property of the task, so that you know whether the invocation has completed and the result is ready. You can also block the current thread until the task is completed, using the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) method. You can also wait asynchronously for the completion of the task, without blocking the current thread, by [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)ing the task.